# for loop in R that gives time-increment in a new column

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I need to add a new column to my data frame that will contain a time increment, say of 2.3 seconds, starting at 2. The reason why I (believe) need a for loop is that the count in the new column has to reset for each subject and condition (both "subjects" and "conditions" are factors in my data fame). So the for-loop would have to loop over both subjects and conditions.

Comment: `@kdopen` No I haven't. If I use `dplyr`, how do I get the time increment in the new column?

Comment: I picked this up in the review queues. The point is really that your question is too broad and you are not showing anyone what you have already tried. `dplyr` and grouping would probably get you there if you install it and read the help.